# Rectangle output on the screen?

Tags: c++, c

The user will input two co ordinates. We have to change them to opposite co ordinates and we should output a rectangle on the screen. Can we do it in C++ ??

Comment: Graphical output is operating-system-dependent. The C language itself doesn't cover it.

Comment: What @luserdroog said is true also for C++. Although you can find libraries for C++ that can help you in the task. E.g. [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) is one.

Answer (score 1):

Sure we can, it's just not quite as simple. You will need an external library to achieve this result - personally I recommend looking into these two tutorials:

[I suggest you learn this if you want 2D graphics](http://www.sdltutorials.com/)

[Or this if you want to go all the way](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/)

With both SDL and OpenGL, once you learn to understand them of course, your issue will be easy to resolve by writing very simple code - writing a rectangle or a similar object is usually the first thing being taught. The difference is that SDL encompasses fairly complex framework that allows you an efficient use of 2D graphics, while OpenGL (which SDL is based upon) is much more difficult to deal with - the reward, on the other hand, is far more freedom in what you can do.